# Ajax returning blank response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a simple script where I just want to see request and response that is sent to server and then recieved at client via Ajax. The server is always returning `Status 500`. What am I doing wrong?
Below is my script.

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
function loginJs()
{

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://my-website.com/ajax_exp.php",true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{  

 alert("State "+xmlhttp.readyState+" Status "+xmlhttp.status);
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
 }
}
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**ajax_exp.php**

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-website.com/ajax_exp.php');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action',        'my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');

function my_action()
{
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

echo $username;
die();
}


?>
```

Comment: `500` means, error on your server. Check your function that is called by AJAX in PHP

Comment: It seems that problem is with your add_action() function.

Answer (score 1):

1) try removing

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-website.com/ajax_exp.php');
 add_action('wp_ajax_my_action',        'my_action');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

replacing with

```
 my_action();
```

You can easily trace the error;

2) Check console log for any javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

Path is the problem provide your server path `ajax/ajax_exp.php`

```
<script>
function loginJs()
{

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/ajax_exp.php",true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{  

 alert("State "+xmlhttp.readyState+" Status "+xmlhttp.status);
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
 }
}
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: there is no path like `ajax/ajax_exp.php` in this path.. See the URL's

Comment: You create one like this path and use

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having the same issue, this is what I did and now it works!

**Javascript**

Replaced `xmlhttp.send();` with `xmlhttp.send(null);`

**PHP**

```
<?php
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
print $username;
?>
```